# Nested enumerate with `\fbox{enumi}` stops incrementing

Tags: enumerate, nesting, fbox

I wanted to have boxes around my item labels of `enumerate`. I created a new command:

```
\newcommand{\sqenumi}{\protect\fbox{\arabic{enumi}}}
```

This way, I can get what I want with `\begin{enumerate}[label=\sqenumi]`.

However, when using `\sqenumi` for an `enumerate` nested in another (with or without `\sqenumi`), the label doesn't increment anymore. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\sqenumi}{\protect\fbox{\arabic{enumi}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sqenumi]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\sqenumi]
            \item Sub item 1
            \item Sub item 2
            \item Sub item 3
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Item 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Gives this result:
[image: nested enumerate with boxes around label not incrementing label]

Comment: the inner list use another counter (enumii), that's why enumitem has the * to represent the current counte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumi` is the counter of the top level enumeration. For the nested enumeration, you would have to use `enumii`, `enumiii` etc. instead.

However you can use the special enumitem syntax `\arabic*`, this will automatically be replaced by the current nesting level

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\sqenumi}{\protect\fbox{\arabic*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sqenumi]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\sqenumi]
            \item Sub item 1
            \item Sub item 2
            \item Sub item 3
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Item 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]